# Angular 9 Bootstrap carousel remains still with no effects

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

In HTML, all is properly ranged and directly equal to the original Bootstrap 4 website:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="../../assets/images/background/promo-bg.jpg" alt="Primera diapositiva">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="../../assets/images/background/promo-bg-2.jpg" alt="Segunda diapositiva">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="../../assets/images/background/promo-bg-3.jpg" alt="Tercera diapositiva">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`styles.css`:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
/*@import '../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/yeti/bootstrap.min.css';*/
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css';
/*Los imports del tema importado*/
@import '../src/assets/css/theme-1.css';
/*@import '../src/assets/fontawesome/js/all.js';*/
@import '../src/assets/plugins/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css';
@import '../src/assets/plugins/flexslider/flexslider.css';
```

The carousel in the HTML page stays still, and I don't get why. All the needed code is already included in the components of the Angular. I took the carrousel from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/
But still, it does not work.

I edit to add the Js calls at the end of home.component.html:
Of course. At the end of the home.component.html there is this code:      <!--

```
jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you imported bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js because those js files are needed for carousel?

Comment: Of course. At the end of the home.component.html there is the code I added to the main article

Comment: Could you please add your JS files in index.html file?

Comment: Excellent! That was the answer!